# How to get period between date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two months, start and end. I want to iterate over all the months in between i.e. I want to extract all the months as string in loop.

```
start = '1905' # May 2019
end = '2003' # March 2020

for month in range(start, end):
     # I want to get string of each month in same format here
```

Could someone please help me in obtaining this cleanly and efficiently? My year will always between (2000-2099)

Comment: A simple way can be two for-loops: The outer for the year, the inner for the months iterating over a list of month names.

Comment: Just a reminder: Until 1958 everyone thought the year would always be between 1900 and 1999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) with convert date strings to datetimes:

```
start = '1905' # May 2019
end = '2003' # March 2020

p = pd.period_range(pd.to_datetime(start, format="%y%m"), 
                    pd.to_datetime(end, format="%y%m"), freq='M')
print (p)
PeriodIndex(['2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10',
             '2019-11', '2019-12', '2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

Then use [`PeriodIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html) for custom format:

```
print (p.strftime('%B'))
Index(['May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
       'December', 'January', 'February', 'March'],
      dtype='object')


for val in p:
    print (val)
```

Comment: that is very compact & nice!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
months = {
            '01': 'Jan',
            '02': 'Feb',
            '03': 'Mar',
            '04': 'Apr',
            '05': 'May',
            '06': 'Jun',
            '07': 'Jul',
            '08': 'Aug',
            '09': 'Sep',
            '10': 'Oct',
            '11': 'Nov',
            '12': 'Dec'
        }

start = '1905'
end = '2003'

for i, j in enumerate(range(int(start[0:2]), int(end[0:2])+1)):
  if i == 0 and start[0:2] != end[0:2]:
    s = int(start[2:4])
    e = 12

  if i > 0 and start[0:2] != end[0:2] and j != int(end[0:2]):

    s = 1
    e = 12

  if i > 0 and start[0:2] != end[0:2] and j == int(end[0:2]):
    s = 1
    e = int(end[2:4]) + 1
    
  if i == 0 and start[0:2] == end[0:2]:

    s = int(start[2:4])
    e = int(end[2:4]) + 1

  for p in range(s, e):
    index = '0' + str(p) if p < 10 else str(p)
    print(f"Year: {j}, month {months[index]}")
    print(f"{j}{index}")
```

Output:

```
Year: 19, month May
1905
Year: 19, month Jun
1906
Year: 19, month Jul
1907
Year: 19, month Aug
1908
Year: 19, month Sep
1909
Year: 19, month Oct
1910
Year: 19, month Nov
1911
Year: 20, month Jan
2001
Year: 20, month Feb
2002
Year: 20, month Mar
2003
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) and its [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import date, datetime

def parse(strg):
    return datetime.strptime(strg, "%y%m").date()

start = parse("1905")
end = parse("2003")
dt = start
while dt <= end:
    print(f"{dt:%y%m}  -  {dt:%B %Y}")
    dt = date(year=dt.year + dt.month // 12, month=(dt.month % 12) + 1, day=1)
```

this will produce the strings

```
1905  -  May 2019
1906  -  June 2019
1907  -  July 2019
1908  -  August 2019
1909  -  September 2019
1910  -  October 2019
1911  -  November 2019
1912  -  December 2019
2001  -  January 2020
2002  -  February 2020
2003  -  March 2020
```

formatting a `date` object with the format string `"%y%m"` will return the format you want.

Comment: Yes my case is bit diff. Although I can pull it from here but I don't think this is the cleanest way to do probably.

Comment: @user13474183 just in case: added an update which may be what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

A generator function like this should do the trick.

```
def parse_yymm_string(yymm_string):
    # Parse an `YYMM` string into a tuple of (Year, Month)
    return (2000 + int(yymm_string[:2], 10), int(yymm_string[2:], 10))


def ym_pair_to_yymm(ym_pair):
    # Convert a (Year, Month) tuple into an `YYMM` string
    return f"{ym_pair[0] - 2000:02d}{ym_pair[1]:02d}"


def generate_yms(start, end): 
    parsed_end = parse_yymm_string(end)
    curr_year, curr_month = parse_yymm_string(start)

    while (curr_year, curr_month) <= parsed_end:
        yield (curr_year, curr_month)
        curr_month += 1
        if curr_month > 12:
            curr_year += 1
            curr_month = 1


start = '1905' # May 2019
end = '2003' # March 2020

for ym in generate_yms('1905', '2003'):
    print(ym, ym_pair_to_yymm(ym))
```

The output is

```
(2019, 5) 1905
(2019, 6) 1906
(2019, 7) 1907
(2019, 8) 1908
(2019, 9) 1909
(2019, 10) 1910
(2019, 11) 1911
(2019, 12) 1912
(2020, 1) 2001
(2020, 2) 2002
(2020, 3) 2003
```